# WebScrape -Getting the href

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

At the end of each row of this page, there is a "View Posters" link that contains a URL.

The first one I have pulled in my code, pulls fine as "ur"

I am not sure how to pull the view poster url.

```
rom selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

val=[]

absinfo=[]
sesinfo=[]

url = 'https://meetings.asco.org/meetings/2022-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/286/program-guide/search?q=&filters=%7B%22sessionType%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Poster%20Session%22%7D%5D%7D'
res=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')


driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)


productlist =driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='session-card']")
#times = soup.select('.time')

for b in productlist:
    ur=b.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `selenium` then try with following `xpath` to identify both the `href` links under the productlist.

```
driver.get("https://meetings.asco.org/meetings/2022-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/286/program-guide/search?q=&filters=%7B%22sessionType%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Poster%20Session%22%7D%5D%7D")

productlist =driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='session-card']")

for item in productlist:
     print("Url 1 :" + item.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@data-cy='sessionTitle']//a").get_attribute('href'))
     print("View Poster :" + item.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[.//span[text()='View Posters']]").get_attribute('href'))
```

**Output:**

```
Url 1 :https://meetings.asco.org/2022-asco-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/14170
View Poster :https://meetings.asco.org/session/14170
Url 1 :https://meetings.asco.org/2022-asco-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/14145
View Poster :https://meetings.asco.org/session/14145
Url 1 :https://meetings.asco.org/2022-asco-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/14169?presentation=205955
View Poster :https://meetings.asco.org/session/14169
Url 1 :https://meetings.asco.org/2022-asco-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/14168
View Poster :https://meetings.asco.org/session/14168
Url 1 :https://meetings.asco.org/2022-asco-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/14450
View Poster :https://meetings.asco.org/session/14450
Url 1 :https://meetings.asco.org/2022-asco-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/14163
View Poster :https://meetings.asco.org/session/14163
Url 1 :https://meetings.asco.org/2022-asco-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/14449
View Poster :https://meetings.asco.org/session/14449
Url 1 :https://meetings.asco.org/2022-asco-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/14451
View Poster :https://meetings.asco.org/session/14451
Url 1 :https://meetings.asco.org/2022-asco-gastrointestinal-cancers-symposium/14166
View Poster :https://meetings.asco.org/session/14166
```